# Code for page.clientscript.registerstartupscript not working

Tags: asp.net

I am using Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(); to show a message on button click in asp.net C#.

The code is shown below :

```
string javaScript1 = "<script language=JavaScript>\n" + "alert('Can't add new entry since course id already exists for the selected year.');\n" + "</script>";
                RegisterStartupScript("image1_ClickScript", javaScript1);
```

This code is written inside button click event function. Same code on same page in another function is working properly, but its not working. I have checked through debugger, there is no error, but the alert box doesnot appear on browser.

Any suggestion will be appreciated in the same direction.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
string javaScript1 = "\n" + "alert('Cant add new entry since course id already exists for the selected year.');\n" + ""; RegisterStartupScript("image1_ClickScript", javaScript1);
```

try this. looks like single quote in **Can't** causing an issue.

Comment: Removing content is not a solution

Answer (score 0):

Try this in a single line:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "msgbox", "alert('Can't add new entry since course id already exists for the selected year.');", true);
```